# Margin after list items in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using this code to show a `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-3">Breakbeat</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-11">Classical</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-16">Downbeat</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-30">Filmmusik</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-24">Folk&amp;Country</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-40">Jazz/Blues</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-48">Latin</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-64">Pop/Mainstream</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-68">Reggae</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-75">Rock</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-81">Techno/Electro</li>
  <li class="even" id="lid-35">Urban</li>
  <li class="odd"  id="lid-88">World</li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
ul span {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0 1px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
} 

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0px 0 2px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Whatever I do, the list items have a bottom margin. Where does it come from? How can I solve that problem?

Comment: It seems to strip the htm, so one more try: '<html> <ul><li class="odd" id="lid-3">Breakbeat</li><li class="even" id="lid-11">Classical</li><li class="odd" id="lid-16">Downbeat</li><li class="even" id="lid-30">Filmmusik</li><li class="odd" id="lid-24">Folk&amp;Country</li><li class="even" id="lid-40">Jazz/Blues</li><li class="odd" id="lid-48">Latin</li></ul></html>'

Comment: @Chris, you can select code and press Ctrl+K to turn it into a code block. (Next time, I already did it for you.)

Comment: Can you post an example on JSFiddle or something? Also, have you used Developer Tools to view what CSS is being applied and from where?

Comment: Created a JSFiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hnsjt/ Tried it in IE6 and couldn't see the problem.

Comment: The (default) browser styles (IE included) don't apply any styles to the `li` box model. It's definitely some succeeding style rules that are overriding your styles. I'd suggest you fire up the developer tools and trace which style is applying a bottom margin to your `li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Set the line-height on the li to 1em - this will make the line-height the same as the font-size.

Even better, set the line-height to 1.4, which gives it a nice spacing so the items don't run together.

This will mean if you increase the size of the font, you won't need to also change the line-height within the li's if you do - and will update if a user sets a larger font-size.

Answer (score 0):

You have a height of 14px.... if you add a line-height of 14px it should fix the problem:

```
ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 2px 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit:
Actually 16 12 works better:

```
ul li {
    padding: 0px 0 2px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    line-height:12px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same markup, and replace all of your CSS with this;

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```