# CSS - li element not displayed properly in IE

Tags: css, list

I'm having problem with displying a li element in IE(8), it looks exactly I want in FF.

IE puts a margin of 4px in the bottom of element. Here is the code. I can remove the margin by adding -4px margin to the element but then it shrinks it in FF.

So basically IE makes my li fatter.

```
#navigation ul {
    width: 176px;
    margin: 0px 1px 2px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 4px #000001;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 4px #000001;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 4px #000001;  
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
    float: left;
}
#navigation li {
    height: 30px;
}
#navigation li:hover {
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
#navigation li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#navigation ul li a {   
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover {
color: blue;
}
#navigation ul li:first-child a {
    border-top: none;
}
#navigation ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Code for the background of li element (many of them - it's like a puzzle of images):

```
#c1l1 { background: url(img/new-1-0-0-0-01-02.png);}
#c1l2 { background: url(img/new-1-0-0-0-01-03.png);}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hey i think you define li,a display:linline-block;

Comment: have you tried to assign margin:0;??

Comment: this seems a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338892/margin-after-list-items-in-ie or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498354/css-gap-between-list-items-in-ie7

Comment: display:linline-block; doesn't help, also padding and margin 0 doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `display: inline;` on `<li>` elements. Just for IE, of course (use conditional comments for that).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

`//margin: -4px;`

Should work for all versions of IE

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've added <!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#navigation li {
 margin:0 0 -4px 0;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: There's no need to use such heavy constructions. `//` is equal. It will be ignored by all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a victim of browser style sheets and their styles. I would recommend resetting the padding and margin on the ul and li elements to 0. This reset should be done before you apply other styles and should be applied for all browsers to get a consistent layout.

Comment: I've got in body body{margin:0;padding:0;}. Is that a reset you are reffering to? I'm new to css and html so excuse me if that's something obvious.

Comment: Those style resets will only apply to the body element. You need to do the following -

<style>

ul, li { marging: 0; padding: 0;}

</style>

Answer (score 0):

try one of these :

1. `float: left` list-items (and then also apply a `clear: left` or you will see them aligned side by side)
2. set `line-height: 30px` to list-items